# Is there any information that Tilly is related to Janeway?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-discovery

Is there any information or hints that Ensign Tilly is possibly an ancestor to Captain Kathryn Janeway?

The whole aspect of Tilly training to become a captain someday, that it's a struggle for her and her red hair lead me to think they may be leading toward this down the road as a Voyager tie-in to connect the series to the canon Voyager series.

Comment: This is called Small-Universe Thinking.

Comment: I do not think it is the case at all. Red hair and Starfleet career can not be considered as any sort of hints from the creators. It's the same as assume T'pol related to Tuvok because they both are vulcans and they serve on a human starship. Or take any other vague matches in the series. Not enough evidence to my opinion.

Comment: “that it's a struggle for her and her red hair” — I don’t remember the command being much of a struggle for Janeway in and of itself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although it's *possible*, there's simply no good evidence that could lead us to believe that Ensign Sylvia Tilly (fl. 2250s) and Captain Kathryn Janeway (DOB approx 2332) are directly related.

That being said, the only things we know about [Janeway's grandparents](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_Humans_(24th_century)#Unnamed_000) are that her grandmother cooked Biryani and that her grandfather made grilled cheese occasionally. We know nothing whatsoever about her great grandparents, nor do we know whether Tilly went on to have any children.